# How to run the blocks of code in cli? PHP

Tags: php, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

In several online resources I've seen the examples like in the picture below. So, How can I run it? Is it possible?

I know about interactive mode (php -a) or run code without using script tags (php -r), but all of them differ from example below..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be from stdin:

```
echo '<?php echo "hello world!"; ?>' | php
```

Another way would be to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>:

```
$ php

<?php
echo "hello world!\n";
?>
^D
hello world
$
```

Comment: Great! However why it outputs the echo on the one solid line. Example above output the following: `hello worlduser@hostname:~$` How can I separate output?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've known a lot of new!))

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if I recall correctly. That's the Unix shortcut for [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) (end of file).

It's normally easier to just use files.

Comment: I don't think so. It's probably using the default shell line editor.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + D is something new to me
To run simple code in php, I used to use `php -r`

```
php -r 'for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) { echo $i . "\n"; }'
```